# Sending / Receiving through a ObjectStream serialization issue

Tags: java, object, serialization, stream

So this is my question.

I have a client and a server java program.
Each one establishes and manages a ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream with the other.

I want to be able to send objects (Given all objects sent will extend a Packet class I made).
The issue is that even though the client and server may have the exact same code for the packet class, I am getting a error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: shared.Packet0Connect
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.mooman219.gmail.server.ReceivePacketThread.run(ReceivePacketThread.java:19)
```

It appears that java thinks that the Packet class on the server is a different class on the client.

Is there a way I can fix this (Aside from having the same package names on both the client and server)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data transport object classes must be the same class -- they must have the same fully qualified class name (i.e. the same package name and the same classname), not just identical contents.

The byte stream emitted by the serialisation process includes the fully qualified class name of the object (as well as the FQCN of the superclasses).  It then also includes the serialised versions of the non-transient, non-static fields (unless you've customised the serialisation process using one of the hook methods).

Here's an [example of the byte stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html#10128).  Note that in the example, the class is in the default (empty) package which makes the illustration of what we're discussing a bit less clear.

Comment: @Joe: why can't you use the exact same class?  Why are you duplicating it on either end?  That violates [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: I wanted to have the exact same class on both ends, just in different packages.

Comment: @Joe: But then it's not the same class.  Why do you want to put it in different packages?

Comment: If it would be better to have the same package names than i'll go that route, I was just hoping that there would be a way to have different names.

Comment: I originally put them in different packages for organization reasons. I guess I am just curious :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12132/discussion-between-joe-and-greg-kopff)

Comment: @Joe If you put the same source code into two different packages, in 12 months' time or less you will have two different classes. If you don't, you won't.